# Info source in new package release e-mail summary

Tags: ros, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Out of curiousity, e.g. [New Packages for Jade and Kinetic 2016-12-15](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-jade-and-kinetic-2016-12-15/975),

- Where are "contributors" taken from? Doesn't look like [all the maintainers listed for moveit metapackage for Kinetic](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/1be521a827ea4f59ddb08af15f0f72031ac27322/moveit/package.xml#L6-L11) are enlisted.
- How is package categorized as "added" or "updated"? MoveIt! for Kinetic has never been publicly synced until this time of sync IMO, but it's in "updated package" category.

---

UPDATE: thanks for taking a look @ahendrix, but in any previous release note `moveit` has not been included for kinetic ([2016-10-24](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-indigo-jade-and-kinetic-2016-10-24/722/1), [2016-10-04](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-kinetic-2016-10-04/544/1)). And now I'm the one of a few who run bloom for moveit so I've been paying attention :) . During soak period we bumped versions a few times.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250145/info-source-in-new-package-release-e-mail-summary/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-12-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-15**:
The sync data shows that the public version was updated: `ros-kinetic-moveit: 0.9.1-2 -> 0.9.3-0`

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-15**:
The GBP repo for moveit also shows multiple previous releases into kinetic: https://github.com/ros-gbp/moveit-release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The report is generated from diffing the debian repositories. The implementation is here: https://goo.gl/kczVY7  Debian control files only support a single maintainer: https://goo.gl/swhwpO so we only get the first maintainer listed at this stage.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-12-17**:
That explains for the fewer maintainers listed in the release report. What  about my other question?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-12-17**:
Same answer. The output of that script for each sync is here: http://build.ros.org:8080/job/Krel_sync-packages-to-main/ I just copy and paste for the announcement.